# I want to start a configure activity on click of android widgets?

Tags: android

For below code...

below code is for the android widget
the same code is on this link Click[here](http://malubu.wordpress.com/2012/06/02/android-app-widgets-and-their-configuration/)

```
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    for (int widgetId : appWidgetIds)
    {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, widgetId);
    }
}
protected static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId)
{
    //Inflate layout.
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.time_weight_layout);
    //Update UI.
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.tvTime, Utility.settemp());
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.tvTitle, Utility.gettitle());      //When user click on the label, update ALL the instances of the widget.
    Intent labelIntent = get_ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE_Intent(context);
    labelIntent.setData(Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.parse("abc" + "://widget/id/"), String.valueOf(appWidgetId)));
    PendingIntent labelPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, appWidgetId, labelIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.tvTime, labelPendingIntent);
    Log.d("updateAppWidget", "Updated ID: " + appWidgetId);
    //Call the Manager to ensure the changes take effect.
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
}
protected static Intent get_ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE_Intent(Context context)
{
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    ComponentName thisAppWidget = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), TimeWidgetProvider.class.getName());
    int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidget);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
    return intent;
}
```

here Main activity is configure activity I want to start MainActivity on click of widget

Comment: You should copy and paste referenced code to your post. Including links in questions or answers is frowned upon and could cost you downvotes (esp using broken links!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [a youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kGHCeu88l1o&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=160) for the same. 
It's only 6 min tut.